# Salesforce Split one object into two(parent-child relationship)

Tags: salesforce, clone, master-detail, records

I have data coming to a salesforce object from a third party tool like this:

ID  |  field1  | field2 | criteria1importance  |  criteria1score  |  criteria1competitorscore | criteria2importance  |  criteria2score  |  criteria2competitorscore  |criteriaN...

i want to split this in a parent child relationship like this :

parent object :
ID  |  field1  | field2 |  criteria(foreign key)

and child object :
criteriaName  | importance  | score  | competitorScore

hope that makes sence, i have been searching for this since 2 weeks :/
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the original object already in SFDC? How are you doing the import? You could use Apex to transform the object. The structure would be a a parent object with the fields <ID, field1, field2> and a child object with the rest of the fields. You should restrict the child object so that it can be created only by code.

Comment: Yes the original object is already in SFDC,
the third party application is a survey tool which transfers answers to SFDC object so i can't modify how they are transfered.

how could i do this in apex code ? have you an example ? i have programming background so just need a simple example.Thanks

Comment: You will need to write logic for this process by yourself. First you need to create empty child object, then fill in all possible fields with values from 'data coming' (I would suggest you to use String.split method for this). Insert it. Then create parent; do the same with it; set id of child to parent's specific field. Insert parent.

Comment: I will maintain the parent object as is and create a child object where i will copy the necassary fields, based on your suggestions i have made some researchs and i found an example of apex trigger "Creating a Child Record When a Parent Record is Created" http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/creating-a-child-record-when-a-parent-record-is-created  i will try to modify this code to fit my needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, i have created the child object and an apex trigger to fill the fields.
this is how it looks like:

```
trigger ResultChildTrigger on VANG_Survey_Result__c (after insert) {
List<SurveyDetail__c> details = new List<SurveyDetail__c>();
for (VANG_Survey_Result__c newResult: Trigger.New) {
    //if (newResult.Id != null) {
        details.add(new SurveyDetail__c(
        Name = 'Overall Sales Approach',
        Survey_Result__c = newResult.Id,
        importance__c = decimal.valueOf(newResult.Q1Value__c),
        score__c = decimal.valueOf(newResult.Q2Value__c),
        competitor_score__c = decimal.valueOf(newResult.Q3Value__c)
        ));  
   }
insert details;
```

}